# How do I zip a directory containing sub directories or files in Golang?

Tags: go, zip

I know it will have to do with the [zip package](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/) I just have no idea how I would implement such a thing.

Comment: The example for writer goes to show most of what is required; https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#example_Writer beyond that you just need to recurse from the top level directory adding everything to the writer.

Answer (score 22):

Here's solution that uses Go's built-in recursive file-walker since the top answer so far has implemented their own file-walker:

---

Aside, some findings I've found while generating zip files today that might save someone else a headache:

- The argument to `w.Create(zippath)` should not start with a "/", and should be relative to the zip root (aka the folder that would be created if you unzipped the archive). So a top-level "manifest.xml" file should be `w.Create("manifest.xml")`. Nested files should be `w.Create("a/b/c.css)`. If you are generating bad/surprising archives, check first to ensure you aren't breaking this rule. My code does not try to enforce this.
- Some specs (like epub) want files in a certain order, but Go's `filepath.Walk` will crawl in lexical order. (For that matter, I've found all epub parsers to be lenient here so far from Calibre to Books.app on macOS). If you need a specific order, then @LeTigre's solution with `ReadDir` will let you sort the files at each level of descent.

---

```golang
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

// Zips "./input" into "./output.zip"
func main() {
    file, err := os.Create("output.zip")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    w := zip.NewWriter(file)
    defer w.Close()

    walker := func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        fmt.Printf("Crawling: %#v\n", path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()

        // Ensure that `path` is not absolute; it should not start with "/".
        // This snippet happens to work because I don't use 
        // absolute paths, but ensure your real-world code 
        // transforms path into a zip-root relative path.
        f, err := w.Create(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(f, file)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }
    err = filepath.Walk("input", walker)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to readall then write. just do io.Copy(dst, src) so currently io.Copy(f, file) Also you are closing w twice, it is not a bug perse but zip.Close does not close the underlying resource AND the destination file opened at the beginning of the program is not being closed. So currently something might go wrong. Also the program is incomplete (no package spec, no import spec etc)

Comment: could be the perfect answer if this was fixed.

Comment: (For the record, my answer does include all of @mh-cbon's suggestions, iirc. Thanks.)

Comment: @mh-cbon Hey! Thanks for your go-msi package.. Although I'm still struggling to get it to work, it nevertheless gave me more insights into WiX

Comment: @Macindows this has little to do with this answer. Though, consider always carefully selecting the package you depend on. Prefer those with regular updates and ideally backers. Though read https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser/issues/1295 there are good alternatives. packaging is a pain in the ass.

Comment: Regarding your comment with the absolute paths: You can use `path.Base(path)` to get the filenames if you want all files to be on one level. Then it doesn't matter if the original path is absolute or relative.

Answer (score 19):

To do it manually, you could modify the code linked above:

[ExampleZipWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#example_Writer)

To give you a simple example, that has many flaws, but might be easily understood:

```
func ZipWriter() {
    baseFolder := "/Users/tom/Desktop/testing/"

    // Get a Buffer to Write To
    outFile, err := os.Create(`/Users/tom/Desktop/zip.zip`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer outFile.Close()

    // Create a new zip archive.
    w := zip.NewWriter(outFile)

    // Add some files to the archive.
    addFiles(w, baseFolder, "")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Make sure to check the error on Close.
    err = w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

We use this to iterate on files recursively to generate folders too:

```
func addFiles(w *zip.Writer, basePath, baseInZip string) {
    // Open the Directory
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(basePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(basePath + file.Name())
        if !file.IsDir() {
            dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile(basePath + file.Name())
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

            // Add some files to the archive.
            f, err := w.Create(baseInZip + file.Name())
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            _, err = f.Write(dat)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        } else if file.IsDir() {

            // Recurse
            newBase := basePath + file.Name() + "/"
            fmt.Println("Recursing and Adding SubDir: " + file.Name())
            fmt.Println("Recursing and Adding SubDir: " + newBase)

            addFiles(w, newBase, baseInZip  + file.Name() + "/")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@danneu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63233911/11381693) is good. But if the directory contains empty subdirectories, the code doesn't work and it will ignore them.

So instead of just returning `nil`, we should create a directory:

```golang
if info.IsDir() {
    // add a trailing slash for creating dir
    path = fmt.Sprintf("%s%c", path, os.PathSeparator)
    _, err = w.Create(path)
    return err
}
```

Answer (score -7):

an ez way to zip directory, you can run command of server:

```
out, err := exec.Command("zip", "-r", "-D", "ideaz.zip", ".idea/*").Output()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Mn-HmUjm5q2

Comment: The zip is not created using go, Also the (Linux / system) package `zip` need to be installed to make this work.