Golang Make MIMETYPE File First File in Zip
I am working on making some modifications to an epub and then rezipping it. I am currently doing this in Golang. The crux of the logic is housed in this repo here. However most of the issue resides in the following logic not setting/copying the mimetype properly:
package filehandler

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/fs"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "github.com/pjkaufman/go-go-gadgets/pkg/logger"
    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

const (
    tempZip = "compress.zip"
    // have to use these or similar permissions to avoid permission denied errors in some cases
    folderPerms fs.FileMode = 0755
    numWorkers  int         = 5
)

// UnzipRunOperationAndRezip starts by deleting the destination directory if it exists,
// then it goes ahead an unzips the contents into the destination directory
// once that is done it runs the operation func on the destination folder
// lastly it rezips the folder back to compress.zip
func UnzipRunOperationAndRezip(src, dest string, operation func()) {
    var err error
    if FolderExists(dest) {
        err = os.RemoveAll(dest)

        if err != nil {
            logger.WriteError(fmt.Sprintf("failed to delete the destination directory %q: %s", dest, err))
        }
    }

    err = Unzip(src, dest)
    if err != nil {
        logger.WriteError(fmt.Sprintf("failed to unzip %q: %s", src, err))
    }

    operation()

    err = Rezip(dest, tempZip)
    if err != nil {
        logger.WriteError(fmt.Sprintf("failed to rezip content for source %q: %s", src, err))
    }

    err = os.RemoveAll(dest)
    if err != nil {
        logger.WriteError(fmt.Sprintf("failed to cleanup the destination directory %q: %s", dest, err))
    }

    MustRename(src, src+".original")
    MustRename(tempZip, src)
}

// Unzip is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24792688
func Unzip(src, dest string) error {
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := r.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    err = os.MkdirAll(dest, folderPerms)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var files = make(chan *zip.File, len(r.File))
    g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(context.Background())
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        g.Go(func() error {
            for {
                select {
                case file, ok := <-files:
                    if ok {
                        wErr := extractAndWriteFile(dest, file)

                        if wErr != nil {
                            return wErr
                        }
                    } else {
                        return nil
                    }
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return ctx.Err()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    for _, f := range r.File {
        files <- f
    }

    close(files)

    return g.Wait()
}

func extractAndWriteFile(dest string, f *zip.File) error {
    rc, err := f.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := rc.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    path := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)

    // Check for ZipSlip (Directory traversal)
    if !strings.HasPrefix(path, filepath.Clean(dest)+string(os.PathSeparator)) {
        return fmt.Errorf("illegal file path: %s", path)
    }

    if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
        err = os.MkdirAll(path, folderPerms)

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    } else {
        err = os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(path), folderPerms)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer func() {
            if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }()

        _, err = io.Copy(f, rc)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

// Rezip is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/63233911
func Rezip(src, dest string) error {
    file, err := os.Create(dest)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer file.Close()

    w := zip.NewWriter(file)
    defer w.Close()

    walker := func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // skip empty directories
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()

        // need a zip relative path to avoid creating extra directories inside of the zip
        var zipRelativePath = strings.Replace(path, src+string(os.PathSeparator), "", 1)
        f, err := w.Create(zipRelativePath)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(f, file)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }
    err = filepath.Walk(src, walker)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

The current problem that I am facing is that when I do this and then run the epubchecker validator on the file I am getting the following message:
ERROR(PKG-006): ./filename.epub(-1,-1): Mimetype file entry is missing or is not the first file in the archive.
Validating using EPUB version 2.0.1 rules.

Check finished with errors
Messages: 0 fatals / 1 error / 0 warnings / 0 infos

EPUBCheck completed

I am not really sure what I need to do to expressly set the mimetype when I create the zip. I did at one time try adding the following logic to the rezip logic just to test if it would properly set the mimetype, but I got an error saying the zip file header was corrupted:
// Rezip is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/63233911
func Rezip(src, dest, mimetype string) error {
    file, err := os.Create(dest)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer file.Close()

    var mtype []byte
    mtype = []byte("application/epub+zip")
    err = binary.Write(file, binary.LittleEndian, mtype)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
...
}

When setting the mimetype failed, I tried copying over the metainf data first and skipping that data in the walking logic, but got the same validation error as prior:
w := zip.NewWriter(file)
    defer w.Close()

    var mimetypePath = src + string(os.PathSeparator) + "META-INF/container.xml"
    err = writeToZip(w, src, mimetypePath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    walker := func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // skip empty directories
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        if mimetypePath == path {
            return nil
        }

        err = writeToZip(w, src, path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }
    err = filepath.Walk(src, walker)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func writeToZip(w *zip.Writer, src, path string) error {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // need a zip relative path to avoid creating extra directories inside of the zip
    var zipRelativePath = strings.Replace(path, src+string(os.PathSeparator), "", 1)
    f, err := w.Create(zipRelativePath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = io.Copy(f, file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

I did see the following two questions that are similar, but they do not answer my question:

Haskell zip package: How to add mimetype file as first file of the archive

Implies the issue may be with capitalization or with the container.xml being compressed


Make MIMETYPE file the first file in an EPUB ZIP file?

Shows some commands to run via the CLI, but does not really help understanding how to fix this in pure Golang



Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong when trying to set/copy the mimetype of the zip file when I create it? Thanks for the help!

it's a well written question.  I don't think you need to extract the zip and write it out to disk.  Can't you just traverse the zip contents one by one, modify the correct files, and copy the rest straight into the destination zip?

I probably could. This is program was originally based on a script where it was easier to just extract the files to a temp dir and then rezip them after the operations were done. Here it could be done without needing a temporary file. But that would not fix the issue with the mimetype getting compressed or whatever the issue is that is going on here. So it is definitely something I can look into doing for a future enhancement.

Can't disagree with that

Ok, so I think I figured it out. I am no longer getting the error when I run the program. Essentially here is what I did to fix the issue:
// start zip file copy with uncompressed mimetype
var mimetypePath = src + string(os.PathSeparator) + "mimetype"
    err = copyMimetypeToZip(w, src, mimetypePath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    walker := func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // skip empty directories
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        // skip the mimetype when it comes to adding compressed files
        if mimetypePath == path {
            return nil
        }

        err = writeToZip(w, src, path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }
...
func copyMimetypeToZip(w *zip.Writer, src, path string) error {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // need a zip relative path to avoid creating extra directories inside of the zip
    var zipRelativePath = strings.Replace(path, src+string(os.PathSeparator), "", 1)
    f, err := w.CreateHeader(&zip.FileHeader{
        Name:   strings.ReplaceAll(zipRelativePath, string(os.PathSeparator), "/"),
        Method: zip.Store,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = io.Copy(f, file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

The issue seems to have been that I was assuming that the mimetype was stored in META-INF/container.xml. This is kind of true, but the error does not refer to this file and as such leaving it uncompressed does not help at all since a file called mimetype needs to be uncompressed at the root of the zip.
Note that I found this question on StackOverflow that explains how to create an uncompressed file in a zip file, but it did not initially solve my problem due to a misconception about which file to leave uncompressed.
